# Laravel Passport authentication issue on AWS server

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel 5.5 with passports for API services. Its working fine after adding the "client credentials" route middleware in local.

```
'client_credentials' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class
```

**Local Setup: **

URL: http://localhost/server/public/index.php/api/v1/user/1

I got response as,

```
{
"status": 200,
"response_time": 0.050323009490967,
"body": {
    "user": "admin",
    "email": "admin@domain.com"
},
"message": "User found"
```

}

**AWS Setup: **

But, when I move to AWS server it won't authenticate.

URI: http://api_server.com/server/public/index.php/api/v1/user/1

I got error as,

```
{
 "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

Both installations are same, and I can get access-token and reset-token by its endpoints.

But POST/GET/PUT/DELETE API calls are now allowed on AWS server.

Why it's not supporting on AWS?

Any other ways to solve this?

[Note: "web" group's "POST/GET/PUT/DELETE" routes are working fine.]

Comment: After uploading to aws did you reconfigure cache again via php artisan config:cache

Comment: Yep, i did the same.

Comment: Also try giving permissions to storage folder ive had issues with aws due to storage permissions

Comment: Yes, i gave 0777 permission to "/storage" directory.

Comment: How did you resolve your issue? I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

you can check for security groups .. where many traffic groups ports are by default blocked.